# ProcessBuilder Force Language

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder

With [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) we can launch native executables like from the `Command Prompt`. Some outputs however depend on the system's language, especially on `Windows`. Having to deal with all possible languages when parsing output becomes significantly more tedious to get things right. Is there a way to force an environment with a specific language set e.g. English in order to "concentrate" on the English language phrases for parsing?

The following code prints out the `ProcessBuilder`'s environment:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
Map<String, String> environment = processBuilder.environment();
for (String key : environment.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(key + ": " + environment.get(key));
}
```

However, it does not contain any language settings so I'm not sure how this can be done.

Comment: How should that work? Theres absolutely no way to guarantee the language by a request. Third-party binaries may come with a specific language hardcoded, same goes for quite a few  of the utilities that come with windows.

Comment: But many utilities change their language depending on the operating system's language setting so what about faking those when invoking the command through `Java`? It might be possible somehow and that's what I'm asking for

Comment: There is no universal way to implement this. If you specify what is your target OS, there is a chance for solution.

Comment: Yeah, the target OS is Windows only

Comment: You could try [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/310214/windows-xp-how-can-i-get-the-system-language-from-command-line#310221). In general altering the system-language in any way will be quite a bit more of effort than just setting an environment-variable.

Comment: @Paul It returns `de;German (Germany)` since the install language was German but my system language is English right now so all command prompt utilities are using English output

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza the parameter used in the example isn't quite correct. `InstallLanguage` regards the OS-language. If you want to alter the user-language instead, you'll have to use this key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\MUILanguagePending`. Note though that this only takes effect after logging out and in again. There's no solution that'll work without that though

Comment: Well, it should work on-the-fly :/